# curl --Digest Authentication with PAW-App

Tags: api, rest, curl, paw-app

Connecting to an API using curl with -u username:api-key --DIGEST works fine. But how to test it with API Clients like PAW-App ?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for the massive delay. Here's the [Digest auth extension](https://luckymarmot.com/paw/extensions/DigestAuthDynamicValue) for Paw. You'll have to install it first.

Then, insert a new header `Authorization` and right-click on the value field, and pick Extensions > Digest Auth:

[image: Use HTTP Digest auth in Paw]

Then, you should be able to edit this, and set your credentials:

[image: Set your credentials for HTTP Digest auth in Paw]

You have a full help topic about Digest Auth in Paw here: https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/auth/digest-auth